# За сколько операций выполняется сравнение строк в C#?

Tags: c#, строки

У меня есть две строки

```
string str1 = "Привет всем";
string str2 = str1;

if(str1 == str2) {

}
```

За сколько операций выполняется сравнение и почему?

И за сколько вот эта?

```
string str1 = "Привет всем";
string str2 = "Привет всем";

if(str1 == str2) {

}
```

Comment: Бред какой-то... Каких операций? И какая оразница?

Comment: `string` - ссылочный тип, так что первая операция просто сравнит по ссылке, а вторая сравнит строки. Так что первая будет несколько быстрее.

Comment: @Qwertiy, ну формально, если исключить интернирование, то в первом случае простое сравнение ссылок, а если тест ссылок провален, тогда уже посимвольно

Comment: @Qwertiy операция сравнения

Comment: @Сергей компилятор достаточно умен, чтобы в место одинаковых строковых литералов подставлять один и тот-же объект. Если ему это не запретили конечно, и контекст позволяет

Comment: @rdorn правильно я понимаю что он сначала будет сравнивать по ссылке, а потом по значению и при любом true из этих вариантов возвращает true?

Comment: @rdorn ну в этом случае да, в общем - никто не гарантирует

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин, думаете правильно если исключить оптимизации компилятора, в вашем случае такие оптимизации будут применены и разницы не будет, в общем случае - по ситуации.

Comment: у вас здесь разница не сравнение строк о представлении синтаксического кода. (компилятор оптимизирует достаточно) два варианта по-любому два  строка ссылается на тот же адрес (потомучто строки одинаковые) в 'Intern Pool'. то есть этот кот вообще не будет влиять на сравнение строк , бессмысленный представление.

Comment: я бы сказал это равносильно написать `if(true) { ... }`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Одинаковы ли ссылки?
2. Является ли хотя бы одна из строк `null`ом?
3. Одинаковы ли длины строк?
4. Сравнение группами по 4 или 2 символа в зависимости от архитектуры процессора.

PS: В коде из вопроса проверка закончится на шаге 1 в обоих случаях.

---

[Оператор bool string](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,661)

```
public static bool operator == (String a, String b) {
   return String.Equals(a, b);
}
```

[Метод Equals String](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,372d790ddae4cbb4)

```
[Pure]
public static bool Equals(String a, String b) {
    if ((Object)a==(Object)b) {
        return true;
    }

    if ((Object)a==null || (Object)b==null) {
        return false;
    }

    if (a.Length != b.Length)
        return false;

    return EqualsHelper(a, b);
}
```

[Метод EqualsHelper String](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,11648d2d83718c5e)

```
[System.Security.SecuritySafeCritical]  // auto-generated
[ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.MayFail)]
private unsafe static bool EqualsHelper(String strA, String strB)
{
    Contract.Requires(strA != null);
    Contract.Requires(strB != null);
    Contract.Requires(strA.Length == strB.Length);

    int length = strA.Length;

    fixed (char* ap = &strA.m_firstChar) fixed (char* bp = &strB.m_firstChar)
    {
        char* a = ap;
        char* b = bp;

        // unroll the loop
#if AMD64
        // for AMD64 bit platform we unroll by 12 and
        // check 3 qword at a time. This is less code
        // than the 32 bit case and is shorter
        // pathlength

        while (length >= 12)
        {
            if (*(long*)a     != *(long*)b) return false;
            if (*(long*)(a+4) != *(long*)(b+4)) return false;
            if (*(long*)(a+8) != *(long*)(b+8)) return false;
            a += 12; b += 12; length -= 12;
        }
#else
        while (length >= 10)
        {
            if (*(int*)a != *(int*)b) return false;
            if (*(int*)(a+2) != *(int*)(b+2)) return false;
            if (*(int*)(a+4) != *(int*)(b+4)) return false;
            if (*(int*)(a+6) != *(int*)(b+6)) return false;
            if (*(int*)(a+8) != *(int*)(b+8)) return false;
            a += 10; b += 10; length -= 10;
        }
#endif

        // This depends on the fact that the String objects are
        // always zero terminated and that the terminating zero is not included
        // in the length. For odd string sizes, the last compare will include
        // the zero terminator.
        while (length > 0) 
        {
            if (*(int*)a != *(int*)b) break;
            a += 2; b += 2; length -= 2;
        }

        return (length <= 0);
    }
}
```