# Размер типов long и int при сравнении строк

Tags: c#, типы-данных

[Смотрю](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/757417/178988) на [код сравнения строк равной длины](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,11648d2d83718c5e), а именно на место, где происходит непосредственно сравнение значений по указателю.

Его суть заключается в том, что за итерацию цикла на AMD64 делается 3 сравнения по 4 символа, а на всех остальных 5 сравнений по 2 символа. Однако, я не могу понять, почему используются типы `long` и `int` - ведь это 8 байт и 4 байта соответственно, а не 4 и 2.

```
    char* a = ap;
    char* b = bp;

#if AMD64
    while (length >= 12)
    {
        if (*(long*)a     != *(long*)b) return false;
        if (*(long*)(a+4) != *(long*)(b+4)) return false;
        if (*(long*)(a+8) != *(long*)(b+8)) return false;
        a += 12; b += 12; length -= 12;
    }
#else
    while (length >= 10)
    {
        if (*(int*)a != *(int*)b) return false;
        if (*(int*)(a+2) != *(int*)(b+2)) return false;
        if (*(int*)(a+4) != *(int*)(b+4)) return false;
        if (*(int*)(a+6) != *(int*)(b+6)) return false;
        if (*(int*)(a+8) != *(int*)(b+8)) return false;
        a += 10; b += 10; length -= 10;
    }
#endif
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Дошло. Это же C#, а не C++. Здесь тип `char` имеет размер 2 байта, а не 1. Поэтому всё верно и `long` - это 8 байт или 4 символа, а `int` - это 4 байта или 2 символа.